# How to save DataFrame as CSV into specific Blob Storage Container (Azure SDKv2)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, azure, azure-blob-storage

In my pipeline I have a final `pandas` `DataFrame`, let's call it `df` which I want to save in the specific Blob Container instance.
This container instance has a URL: `https://mycontainer1234.blob.core.windows.net/files`

Let's create sample `dataframe` for that purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create sample data
data = {
    "Name": [f"Person {i}" for i in range(1, 51)],
    "Age": [random.randint(18, 60) for _ in range(50)]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The thing is I have many many other containers within this instance but I want to save in the specific one. Besides that this container have private access and it should not be public.

Previously in SDKv1 there was a possibility to save using so called `Target Datastore` but in the SDKv2 it's not a thing anymore.

Thank you very much in advance.

P.S. As I understand `uri_file` and `uri_folder` are entities which are referring to the file in the `blob`. But how to create file which is not yet there...

Comment: Hi @Egorsky Are you fine with using `blobServiceclient` instance or `abfs` protocol.?

Comment: @Venkatesan, unfortunately I'm not familiar with that. But as the matter of fact I guess whatever is there by default (I mean can be loaded by using `import`) is fine for me

Comment: Check the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to save DataFrame as CSV into specific Blob Storage Container

You can use the below code to save DataFrame as CSV into a specific storage Container.

**Method 1:**

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

data = {
    "Name": [f"Person {i}" for i in range(1, 51)],
    "Age": [random.randint(18, 60) for _ in range(50)]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the URI of the container you want to upload to
container_uri = "https://<Your-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<Your-container-name>"

sas_token="?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-08-28T18:43:34Z&st=2023-08-28T10:43:34Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxx"  # your sas -token
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(container_uri + "/sample_data.csv" + sas_token)
csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
blob_client.upload_blob(csv_data)
```

**Portal:**
[image]

From the above code, you need a **`sas-token`** you can get from the portal.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Method 2 (abfs protocol):**

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create sample data
data = {
    "Name": [f"Person {i}" for i in range(1, 51)],
    "Age": [random.randint(18, 60) for _ in range(50)]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv('abfs://<Your-container-name>@<Your-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/sample326.csv',storage_options = {'account_key' : 'Your-account-key'}
```

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

- [azure.storage.blob.BlobClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-from-blob-url)
- [Tutorial: Use Pandas to read/write ADLS data in serverless Apache Spark pool in Synapse Analytics - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool#readwrite-data-using-secondary-adls-account)